# Bazel cc_library dependency on other cc_library when each compile with a different crosstool

Tags: bazel

I have a code generator tool that generates C/C++ code. This code generator tool is compiled with crosstool1. The generated C/C++ code needs to be compiled with crosstool2.

So the actions are:

> - Using Crosstool1 compile 'code_generator'.
> - Execute 'code_generator' and generate 'generated_code.cpp'
> - Using Crosstool2 compile 'generated_code.cpp'

Is it possible to make a cc_library() determine the crosstool to use? I saw that Skylark rules now allow a 'toolchains' parameter which I'm not sure how this is used, also I do not want to do the heavy lifting of C/C++ compiling bare bone with Skylark.

Is there an example of using a proper Host Crosstool and Target Crosstool except for the Tenserflow example? I get a headache each time I read it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `//crosstool1:toolchain` is a label for cc_toolchain_suite rule describing first crosstool, `//crosstool2:toolchain` is a label for cc_toolchain_suite for second crosstool, and the build file for the project is:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "generator",
    srcs = [ "main.cc" ],
)

genrule(
    name = "generate",
    outs = ["generated.cc"],
    cmd = "$(location :generator) > $@",
    tools = [":generator"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "generated",
    srcs = [ "generated.cc" ],
)
```

Then running:

```
bazel build --host_crosstool_top=//crosstool1:toolchain --crosstool_top=//crosstool2:toolchain :generated
```

will do exactly what you describe, it will use crosstool1 to build :generator, and crosstool2 to build generated. Genrules use host configuration by default, so all should just work.